# C# - Possible to detect when DataBound?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I would like to cache some UI-specific properties only at the time an object is DataBound, if it gets bound.

Say I have

```
public interface IAmA<T> ()
{
    T Value {get;set;}
}
public class MyString : IAmA<string>, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string _value = String.Empty;
    public virtual string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this._value;
        }
        set
        {
            this._value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement an action or event to fire at the time the object is databound?

```
event Action OnDataBound { ... }
```

So I can detect, say, when

```
MyString myStrObj = new MyString("text");
myStrObj.OnDataBound += CacheUIElements();
Do.OtherStuff();
otherObj.DataSource = myStrObj; //causes CacheUIElements() to fire
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very well do it in the property setter and call the Delegate.

In above case it will be for the OtherObj.DataSource. Because you want the Action to get triggered when you are setting the datasource. So it should be in the setter of whichever property where you want the action to trigger.

```
class OtherClass
{
    DataSource
    {
      get{return _dataSource}
      set
         { 
          _dataSource = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("DataSource");
          OnDataBound();
         }
    }
}
```

If not, assuming OtherClass Implements OnPropertyChanged and triggers for DataSource like this, If its a framework element for sure it will implement NotifyPropertyChanged for DataSource because only then UI will refresh with the changes.

```
class OtherClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DataSource
    {
      get{return _dataSource}
      set
         { 
          _dataSource = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("DataSource");
         }
    }
}
```

Then you can subscribe to this event and check against the property name and trigger the OnDataBound(); e.g:

```
otherClassObj.PropertyChanged += OtherClassPropertyChanged()

private void OtherClassPropertyChanged(Obj sender, PropertyChangedEventargs e)
{
  if(e.PropertyName = "DataSource")
  {
    OnDataBound();
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I can already fire OnPropertyChanged if the Value is changed, I've edited the original question with more details.

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to avoid, if possible. I want to implement it in the original class, so I can use it with arbitrary types - or anything that implements data binding.

Comment: Does your original class - `OtherClass` implement property changed event? and trigger PropertyChanged("DataSource") by any chance?

Comment: This works for me, It's just literally subscribing to the OtherClass's PropertyChanged event in order to "detect" it in the inner object. Thank you.